# Sitemap для поста с разной географией

Tags: sitemap

Здравствуйте, есть сайт где много постов и каждый из них доступен по такому адресу:

```
mydomen.ru/idPost/post_name,
```

так же каждый имеет географию показа, например если юзер выбрал показать только по Москве то имеет и еще такой адрес:

```
mydomen.ru/idPost/москва/post_name,
```

а если выбрал показать по Московской области то будет и московская область и ее города например:

```
mydomen.ru/idPost/московская_область/post_name, 
mydomen.ru/idPost/москва/post_name, 
mydomen.ru/idPost/абрамцево/post_name, 
mydomen.ru/idPost/алабино/post_name,
```

и так далее по альфавиту городов Московской области, так же можно выбрать показать по всей России тогда получается пост будет иметь

```
mydomen.ru/idPost/россия/post_name, 
mydomen.ru/idPost/московская_область/post_name,
```

и так далее все регионы нашей необъятной страны и городов этих регионов. И вот таким образом один пост если имеет показ по всей России то у него очень много url адресов получается примерно около 4000, вот теперь думаю стоит ли sitemap создать или есть другие варианты?

P.S. ёмаё если 1000 постов имеет показ по все России то это получается 4000 000 адресов, как на это сервер реагировать будет когда роботы войдут проверять?

Comment: Ну где же вы профессионалы? Нужна ваша подсказка

Comment: В ситемап добавляйте ссылка вида:

    mydomen.ru/idPost/post_name

Все остальные ссылки в вашем посте, нужно закрывать в robots.txt, так как это сортировка, а сортировка это дубли страниц, а ПС к этому негативно относится.

Comment: во как, спасибо, жить стало легче